# Programmatically select itself inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableViewCell with a UICollectionViewCell inside. I want the user to be able to scroll the UICollectionViewCell but when he taps anywhere inside the UITableViewCell I need it to be selected. Currently when the user taps the UITableViewCell outside the UICollectionViewCell it is selected properly, but when he taps inside the UICollectionViewCell nothing happens. My idea is to implement the collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method inside the UITableViewCell and programmatically trigger a "self selection", but I can't seem to find a way to do this. If I store a reference to the table and the indexPath of the cell inside itself I will probably be able to do it, but I have a feeling that this would be a bad way of doing it. How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for this, though I don't know if it's the best one.

First, I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UICollectionView` inside my `UITableViewCell`, to override the component's one.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    ...
    UITapGestureRecognizer *v_CollectionViewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onClickCollectionView)];
    [self.m_CollectionView addGestureRecognizer:v_CollectionViewTap];
    ...
}
```

Second I created a block property to hold the code for the programatic selection of a row and created a method that calls this block, setting it as the action for the previously created `UIGestureRecognizer`.

```
typedef void (^OnClickTableViewCellBlock)();
@property (nonatomic, copy) OnClickTableViewCellBlock m_OnClickBlock;
```

Last, when I'm creating the `UITableViewCell`, in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I pass a block that calls the `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` one.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    v_Cell.m_OnClickBlock = ^void()
    {
        [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    };
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the UITableViewCell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is blocking the UICollectionViewCell's collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

I would first check if that's the case by putting breakpoints for the UITableViewCell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath: while selecting the UICollectionViewCell.

If that's the case, this answer might help you (comes with a nice tutorial too): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120673/5465258

I think they have a similar problem to what you had.

Comment: I think this question you posted here is the opposite of what I need. What I want it that when the user taps a cell inside the UICollectionViewCell the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: from the UITableView is called! I can capture the tap inside the UICollectionViewCell, now I need to know how to trigger a selection on the UITableViewCell!

Comment: Well, if you have the indexPath of the UITableViewCell, then you can call this `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ROW_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT inSection:SECTION_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT]
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
`

Comment: the thing is, if I'm going to implement this inside the collectionView: didDeselectItemAtIndexPath: (which is inside the UITableViewCell's code) I don't have a reference to the UITableView!

Comment: Sounds like you should put the `Delegate` and `DataSource` of the `UICollectionView` inside your `UITableView`. This link might help: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Answer (score 0):

My solution was essentially the same as accepted answer, except I'm using Swift and decided to use delegation.

Inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass - `CustomCell` in this case - create your delegate as below (making sure to add a property for `IndexPath`), and wire up the `UITapGestureRecognizer` similar to the accepted answer:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func collectionViewTapped(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    ...
    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    
    @objc func onTapCollection() {
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            delegate?.collectionViewTapped(forIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let collectionViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTapCollection))
        collectionViewTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(collectionViewTap)
    }
    ...
}
```

And then just have your `UITableViewController` implement your `CustomCellDelegate`, and assign the delegate and `IndexPath` for your cell in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    ...
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        // cell here is my CustomCell that I set up
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
    ...
}

extension MyViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
    func collectionViewTapped(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```